How to tune the TikZ marking code more elegant?
I use the following TikZ commands to draw the followng figure:
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NN}{9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        ->-/.style = {
            decoration={
                markings,% \fpeval here is not so elegant
                mark=between positions \fpeval{.55*{#1}/(2*{#1}+1)} and \fpeval{{#1}/(2*{#1}+1)} step \fpeval{{#1}/(2*{#1}+1)} with {\arrow{Stealth[scale=1.2]}},
                mark=between positions \fpeval{1.58*{#1}/(2*{#1}+1)} and \fpeval{(2*{#1})/(2*{#1}+1)} step \fpeval{{#1}/(2*{#1}+1)} with {\arrow{Stealth[scale=1.2]}},
                mark=between positions \fpeval{(2*{#1}+.63)/(2*{#1}+1)} and 1 step \fpeval{1/2*(2*{#1}+1)} with {\arrow{Stealth[scale=1.2]}},
            },postaction={decorate},semithick
        },
        ->-end/.style = {
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=between positions .25 and .78 step .8 with {\arrow{Stealth[scale=1.2]}},
                mark=between positions .78 and 1 step .8 with {\arrow{Stealth[scale=1.2]}},
            },postaction={decorate},semithick
        },line cap=round,line join=round,
    ]
        \draw (-.21,-.21) node {$O$};
        \draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (\fpeval{\NN+.5},0)
        node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,\fpeval{\NN+.5})
        node[anchor=south east] {$y$ };
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\NN}
        \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt)
            node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\NN}
            \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm)
            node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nowx}{0}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nowy}{1}
        \foreach \t in {1,...,\NN}{
            \ifnum\t=\NN\relax
                \ifodd\t\relax
                    \path[draw=magenta,->-end] (\nowx,\nowy) -- ++(\t,0) -- ++(0,-\t);
                    % \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpx{\nowx+\t+1}
                    % \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpy{\nowy-\t}
                \else
                    \path[draw=cyan,->-end] (\nowx,\nowy) -- ++(0,\t) -- ++(-\t,0);
                    % \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpx{\nowx-\t}
                    % \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpy{\nowy+\t+1}
                \fi
            \else
                \ifodd\t\relax
                    \path[draw=magenta,->-=\t] (\nowx,\nowy) -- ++(\t,0) -- ++(0,-\t) -- ++(1,0);
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpx{\nowx+\t+1}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpy{\nowy-\t}
                \else
                    \path[draw=cyan,->-=\t] (\nowx,\nowy) -- ++(0,\t) -- ++(-\t,0) -- ++(0,1);
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpx{\nowx-\t}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpy{\nowy+\t+1}
                \fi
            \fi
            \global\let\nowx\tmpx
            \global\let\nowy\tmpy
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Howevet there remains some question I think that can be tuned:

the setting of mark=between positions #1 and #2 step #3 with {\arrow{Stealth[scale=1.2]}} in my case is not precise and not elegant, I want command like \draw[->-] (A) -- ++(1,0) --++(0,1) --++(3,4) could produce only one centered arrow in each sub part, but I fould that difficult to control in my example, is there any advice?
In my case I don't want the LAST loop(i.e. \t=\NN in \ifnum logic) to draw the third path, with \ifnum I succeed, but it cause plenty of dummy code, is there good method to solve the problem like the special case in the Last Or Fisrt in TikZ?
The global varible \nowx and \nowy consulting the link, I think because the group inside the \foreach, we can fix it via \global\let\nowx\tmpx, but if with a lot of situation in the code I need the variable in forloop to be global, it's not convient. Is there any better choice? thanks!


Instead of \nowx and \nowy just use a coordinate, PGF/TikZ remembers it globally anyway.

I prefer my arrow pic in this case. As it is a pic it can be placed along a path operation that has a timer. With the use of the to path operation (defaults to a line to to path, i.e. --) we can use edge node to add the pic automatically to every path operation.
The primitive \ifodd is still used to select arrow even or arrow odd which are just two definitions of paths (and color). There's probably some generalization possible since these two are just mirrored versions of each other but positioning nodes would make this a bit more complicated than it needs to be.
For example:
@arrow/.style n args={5}{
  insert path={(#2:#1) node[arrow node, #3]{$#1$} to (#1,#1)
            to (#4:#1) node[arrow node, #5]{$#1$}
            \unless\ifnum#1=\NN to ++(#4:1)\fi}},
arrow  odd/.style={magenta, @arrow={#1}{up}{left}{right}{below}},
arrow even/.style={cyan,    @arrow={#1}{right}{below}{up}{left}},

I'm also using another primitive \ifnum to not draw the last bit.
I'm using line cap=rect for the colored lines, I've added a detail picture to show how this will draw the lines.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  arrow shift factor/.initial=.5,
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    setup code=\pgfarrowtotallength{#1}\pgftransformxshift{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow shift factor})*\csname pgf@x\endcsname},
    code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  arrow odd/.style={
    magenta,
    insert path={(0,#1) node[arrow node, left ]{$#1$} to (#1,#1)
              to (#1,0) node[arrow node, below]{$#1$}
              \unless\ifnum#1=\NN to ++(right:1)\fi}},
  arrow even/.style={
    cyan,
    insert path={(#1,0) node[arrow node, below]{$#1$} to (#1,#1)
              to (0,#1) node[arrow node, left ]{$#1$}
              \unless\ifnum#1=\NN to ++(   up:1)\fi}},
  arrow even or odd/.style={
    thick, line cap=rect,
    every to/.append style={edge node={pic[midway]{arrow={Stealth[scale=1.2]}}}}
  },
  arrow node/.style=black,
]
\newcommand*\NN{9}
\node[below left]{$O$};
% the 5mm specified with these shifts don't scale
% if you scale the xyz coordinate system, i.e.
% the axis always overshoot about 5mm
\draw[->] ([yshift=+-5mm]0,0) -- ([yshift=+5mm]   up:\NN) node[above left ]{$y$};
\draw[->] ([xshift=+-5mm]0,0) -- ([xshift=+5mm]right:\NN) node[below right]{$x$};
\foreach \i in {1, ..., \NN}
  \draw[
    arrow even or odd,
    arrow \ifodd\i\space odd\else even\fi=\i];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output

line cap=rect: 
line cap=butt: 

A problem lie in the thought of put the path into the arrow style with the option insert path, in normal case I will attach the arrow style to the path, how to come up with such elegant solution? Maybe I should practice and practice in TikZing....

Thanks for yr elegant solution, it really took me some time to make sense the brilliant options in the answer. And the most difficult part of yr code for me is the setup code=\pgfarrowtotallength{#1}\pgftransformxshift{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow shift factor})*\csname pgf@x\endcsname}, it's like a magic for me with such pgf commands to create the arrow, any suggestion for me to make it sense? texdoc pgfplot?

@Explorer \pgftransformxshift is just the PGF version of xshift. \pgfarrowtotallength and \pgfarrowdraw are internal/undocumented macros. The first one return the length of the arrow in \pgf@x and the second one just draws the tip (it is also used by \arrow in the markings decoration). \pgfkeysvalueof just returns the value of the given key and \csname pgf@x\endcsname is used in place of \pgf@x to not have \makeatletter and \makeatother. It is texdoc pgfmanual.

A entirely different approach, and perhaps only a starting point:

Create two styles and apply one or another if the counter is even or odd. In one of them interchange the axes.
Draw the arrowheads as a \pics

Something like this:
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{
  style0/.style={thick,cyan,x={(0,1cm)},y={(1cm,0)}},
  style1/.style={thick,magenta},
  pics/arrowhead/.style={code=%
  {
    \fill (0,0) ++ (0.15,0) --++ (-0.3,0.1) --++ (0,-0.2) -- cycle;
  }}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (9.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,9.5) node[above left]  {$y$};
\foreach\i in {1,...,9}
{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{mod(\i,2)}
  \draw (\i,0.1) --++ (0,-0.2) node[below] {$\i$};
  \draw (0.1,\i) --++ (-0.2,0) node[left]  {$\i$};
  \draw[style\j] (0,\i) -- (\i,\i) -- (\i,0);
  \pic[style\j]                  at (0.5*\i,\i) {arrowhead};
  \pic[style\j,rotate=90-180*\j] at (\i,0.5*\i) {arrowhead};
  \ifnum\i<9 
    \draw[style\j] (\i,0) --++ (1,0);
    \pic[style\j] at (\i+0.5,0) {arrowhead};
  \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



For arrows in lines I would use ext.arrows library and for coloring and define arrows direction \ifodd macro:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                ext.arrows
                }
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NN}{9}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
->-/.style = {decoration={markings,% \fpeval here is not so elegant
                mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{Centered Stealth[scale=1.2]}},
                mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{Centered Stealth[scale=1.2]}},
                         },
                postaction={decorate},semithick, cap=round
             },
  X/.style = {font=\footnotesize, text=black, anchor=#1},
->-L/.style = {decoration={markings,% \fpeval here is not so elegant
                mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Centered Stealth[scale=1.2]}},
                         },
                postaction={decorate},semithick, cap=round
             },
    ]
\draw[-Straight Barb, very thin] (-0.5,0) -- (\NN+0.5,0)   node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw[-Straight Barb, very thin] (0,-0.5) -- (0,\NN+0.5)   node[anchor=south east] {$y$};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\NN}
{
\ifodd\i    
    \draw[->-,purple]   (0,\i) node[X=east]  {$\i$} -| (\i,0) node[X=north]  {$\i$};
    \ifnum\i<\NN    \draw[->-L,purple]  (\i,0) -- ++ (1,0); \fi
\else
    \draw[->-,cyan]     (\i,0) node[X=north] {$\i$} |- (0,\i) node[X=east]    {$\i$};
    \ifnum\i<\NN    \draw[->-L,cyan]  (0,\i) -- ++ (0,1); \fi
\fi
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks uuu for yr answer!!! It remains the little warning:Missing character: There is no ; ("3B) in font nullfont! with the ; after \fi in \ifodd.

That is awesome, by sperate TWO arrow styles into the 0.25 & 0.75 and 0.5 of two kinds, it actually ,make the \path moree elegant, it helps me a lot.

@Explorer, ups ; should be before \fi not after. Corrected now. If you liked answer you may consider to accept it .

aha, I like yr answer, but the configure of two styles is not so elegant, I prefer more fixeible arrow setting not with the fixed set position .25 and .75 with the midway arrow by Qrrbrbirlbel. In all, I appreciated all the answer and the sincere kindness!

@Explorer, ok. Than you will not use my approach with two definition od line styles.

A simple solution... without any testing.
\documentclass[margin=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,ext.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \def\NN{9}
  \node[anchor=north east]{$O$};
  \draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (\NN+.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,\NN+.5) node[anchor=south east] {$y$};
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\NN}{
    \draw (\x,0) ++(0,1pt) -- ++(0,-2pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \draw (0,\x) ++(1pt,0) -- ++(-2pt,0) node[anchor=east] {$\x$};
  }
  \tikzset{middle arrow/.style={semithick,draw=#1,postaction={decorate},
      decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Centered Stealth[scale=1.2]}}}}
  }
  \foreach \x in {1,3,...,\NN}{
    \draw[middle arrow=magenta] (0,\x) -- (\x,\x);
    \draw[middle arrow=magenta] (\x,\x) -- (\x,0);
  }
  \foreach[parse=true] \x in {1,3,...,\NN-1}{
    \draw[middle arrow=magenta] (\x,0) -- (\x+1,0);
  }
  \foreach \x in {2,4,...,\NN}{
    \draw[middle arrow=cyan] (\x,0) -- (\x,\x);
    \draw[middle arrow=cyan] (\x,\x) -- (0,\x); 
  }
  \foreach[parse=true] \x in {2,4,...,\NN-1}{
    \draw[middle arrow=cyan] (0,\x) -- (0,\x+1);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




I propose a solution that makes the arrows as decorations.  There is a parameter \N that can take any odd integer value.  For example, for \N=7 we get the fijgure below.

The code
\documentclass[11pt, margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,
  evaluate={integer \N; \N = 9;},
  decoration={markings,% switch on markings
    mark=at position .51 with {\arrow[thick]{stealth}}
  }]
  % the axes
  \draw[->] (-.5, 0) -- ++(\N +1.5, 0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, -.5) -- ++(0, \N +1.5) node[left] {$y$};
  \foreach \j in {1, 2, ..., \N}{%
    \path (\j, 0) node[below] {$\j$};
    \path (0, \j) node[left] {$\j$};
  }
  
  % the curve
  \foreach \j in {1, 3, ..., \N}{%
    \draw[red, thick, postaction={decorate}] (0, \j) -- ++(\j, 0);
    \draw[red, thick, postaction={decorate}] (\j, \j) -- ++(0, -\j);
  }
  \foreach[parse=true] \j in {2, 4, ..., \N -1}{%
    \draw[red, thick, postaction={decorate}] (\j -1, 0) -- ++(1, 0);
    \draw[blue, thick, postaction={decorate}] (\j, 0) -- ++(0, \j);
    \draw[blue, thick, postaction={decorate}] (\j, \j) -- ++(-\j, 0);
    \draw[blue, thick, postaction={decorate}] (0, \j) -- ++(0, 1);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Less can be more ... so putting fewer arrows may improve the visual and needs less sophisticated code. However, some solutions for more arrows where given in the other answers.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand\mnline[1]{\draw[magenta,->,dashed] (0,#1) -- (#1,#1) -- (#1,0);}
\newcommand\maline[1]{\draw[magenta,->] (0,#1) -- (#1,#1) -- (#1,0) -- +(1,0);}
\newcommand\cyline[1]{\draw[cyan   ,->] (#1,0) -- (#1,#1) -- (0,#1) -- +(0,1);}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth}]
    % ~~~ coordinate system ~~~~~~~~
    \draw[<->]  (10, 0)node[anchor=north west]{$x$} -- 
                ( 0, 0)node[anchor=north east]{$O$} -- 
                ( 0,10)node[anchor=south east]{$y$};
    \draw (-.5,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,-.5);
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,...,9}\node[anchor=north] at (\x,0){\x};
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3,...,9}\node[anchor=east ] at (0,\y){\y};
    
    % ~~~ lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    \foreach \i in {1,3,5,7} \maline{\i};
    \mnline{9}
    \foreach \i in {2,4,6,8} \cyline{\i};   
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

